# Как подключить Android Studio к Visual Studio Emulator for Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Пишу приложение для Android в Android Studio. Хочу отлаживать его в Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android (он работает на AMD в отличие от родных эмуляторов от Google). Установил и запустил Visual Studio Emulator, однако в списке доступных устройств в Android Studio он не появился.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно сделать, чтобы Android Studio увидела этот эмулятор как устройство для отладки?

Answer (score 1):

Эта проблема описан в [документации Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/cross-platform/troubleshooting-the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN#ADB). В ней предлагается решить её при помощи изменения настроек реестра.

> он работает на AMD в отличие от родных эмуляторов от Google

Заблуждаетесь. Штатный эмулятор можно запустить на AMD. Даже с образами Android x86 вместо тормозных AMR. Правда для этого потребуется Win 10 Pro с включённой поддержкой Hyper-V.

Если использование Win 10 Pro с Hyper-V по каким-то причинам недоступно, можно использовать [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). Работает почти везде (лишь бы процессор поддерживал виртуализацию) и Android Studio его распознаёт без проблем.

Comment: Ссылка как настроить штатный: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на настройку штатного эмулятора. Оказывается они поддерживают AMD, по крайней мере на словах. Сходу запустить не удалось, надо будет поразбиратся.

Comment: По поводу ссылки на документацию Microsoft - видимо эта статья устарела. У меня в реестре нет пути, который там предлагают поправить: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android SDK Tools

Comment: Кажется разобрался - при первоначальном скачивании он пишет что вроде того, что скачивается образ для Intel, потом при запуске пишет что не найден Intel и выходит, однако если запустить ещё раз, то запускается.